# Is it possible to reach a deadlock?

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock

I am struggling trying to figure out how deadlocking works...

```
public void withdraw(double amount) {
  balanceChangeLock.lock();
  try {
      while (balance < amount) {} // wait balance to grow ...
      double nb = balance - amount;
      balance = nb; 
  } ﬁnally {
      balanceChangeLock.unlock();
 }
}
```

edit: more code i left out

```
public void deposit(double amount){
  balanceChangeLock.lock();
  try{
    balance = balance + amount;
  } finally {
    balanceChangeLock.unlock();
 }
}
```

Is it possible to reach deadlock with this code?

This is not homework, I have a final and this is on my teacher's notes I'm reviewing and I dont quite understand it

Comment: Depends how the balance grows.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework assignment.  Are you actually getting deadlock in your program?  Are you writing a program that involves locks?  Try reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Comment: and whether it can grow while balanceChangeLock is locked.

Comment: Deadlocking requires at least two threads. If you want an answer, consider posting some relevant code from your other threads.

Comment: What is the type of `balanceChangeLock`?

Comment: A deadlock requires two threads and two locks. At least.

Comment: Deadlock requires at least two shared resources that can be independently locked by competing processes.  So if process `A` locks resource `One` but needs `Two` as well to complete its task, while resource `Two` is locked by process `B` which in turn needs `One` for its completion you would have a deadlock, providing that both processes are in a *wait forever* mode.

Comment: I would hope no teacher would illustrate financial transactions with floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you understand what a deadlock is via a simple example:

We have two threads `(T1, T2)`
We have two locks `(L1, L2)`
We have two critical critical operations `(OP1 and OP2)` that requires the acquisition of `L1` and `L2` to execute

The following execution order occurs:

```
T1 begins executing OP1
T2 begins executing OP2
T1 acquires L1 as part of OP1
T2 acquires L2 as part of OP2
T1 attempts to acquire L2 and is blocked because L2 is currently held by T1
T2 attempts to acquire L1 and is blocked because L1 is currently held by T1
```

hence, we are in a deadly embrace.  This is just a simple example.  It will help if you create a diagram with the above scenario to see it play out.  Notice that the order in which the locks were acquired was critical to making the deadlock manifest.  This is part of why these problems are intermittent and notoriously difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deadlock can occur here.

Here is the a possible flow of execution that would cause deadlock

1. `withdraw` is called and the balance isn't large enough to with draw the amount.  Therefore, the code stays in the while loop and holds the lock.
2. `deposit` is called and tries to lock `balanceChangeLock` but it cannot because `withdraw` has the lock. So it waits.

Now `withdraw` is waiting for a deposit and `deposit` is waiting for the lock to be released.  The code will not continue in either thread and you have deadlock.

Comment: Quote Wikipedia on Deadlock: "A deadlock is a situation in which two or more competing actions are each waiting for the other to finish, and thus neither ever does."  This is a deadlock, because `deposit` is waiting for the lock to be released by `withdraw` and `withdraw` is waiting for a deposit to be made by `deposit`.  In order to avoid deadlock, `withdraw` should release its lock before entering the while loop that waits for a deposit.

Comment: The Wikipedia definition is too broad. It covers spin loops like this one for example. A proper definition requires two or more processes and two or more resources.

Comment: @EJP, will you provide a link to the proper definition of "deadlock"?  Wikipedia has this to say on spin locks "wait in a loop ("spin") while repeatedly checking if the lock is available."  The OP's code is not checking if a lock is available in the while loop, it's checking if a condition has occurred.  I don't want to claim that Wikipedia is the authoritative source on what deadlock and spin lock is, but I would like a reference for the definitions you would like to use.

Comment: Okay, so if you read the complete article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock , you're right that this is not a deadlock.  As you say, there needs to be a lock on two different resources. Sorry.

Comment: I didn't say 'spin lock'. I said 'spin loop'. I would describe this situation as starvation, not as a deadlock. Douglas Lea gives this definition: 'deadlock is possible when two or more objects are mutually accessible from two or more threads, and each thread holds one lock while tryinh to obtain another lock already held by another thread' (*Concurrent Programming in Java,* #2.2.5).